# Matching the second to the last word

Tags: regex

I have the following line:

`19 crooks highway Ontario`

I want to match anything that comes before the last space (whitespace). So, in this case, I want to get back

`highway`

I tried this:

```
([^\s]+)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a lookahead to do it:

```
\S+(?=\s\S*$)
```

```
\S+       any non-whitespace characters, repeat 1+ times (equivolent to [^\s]+)
(?=...)   lookahead, the string after the previous match must satifies the condition inside
\s\S*$    any non-whitespace characters preceded by a whitespace, then the end of the string
```

See the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/BfcsPs/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`\s+(\S+)\s+\S*$`

1. Use `$` anchor to match the end of the line
2. `\s+\S*$` matches one or more spaces followed by zero or more non-whitespaces at the end of the line
3. The desired result is captured in the capturing group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A6OCGO/1)